# [desktop_multi_window]About the multi-window problem, how to listen for window closing after multi-window opening

Tags: linux

Now I use [desktop_multi_window] to create multiple Windows. The main window remains unchanged, what operations it does after the auxiliary window disappears, and why the widget on the window doesn't call dispose method after the window disappears. How do I listen for the close button in the upper left corner of the window?

I tried to listen natively, but it didn't seem to work, I used the close window plugin (flutter_window_close), but it only works on the main window, what do I do about that